# gl-matrix "cannot read property 0 of undefined" in webgl application

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

I began learning webgl by reading Apress's Beginning WebGl for HTML5, it recommends gl-matrix.js to deal with matrix operations, when using the mat4.translate function
which has the following implementation

```js
mat4.translate = function (out, a, v) {
    var x = v[0], y = v[1], z = v[2],
    a00, a01, a02, a03,
    a10, a11, a12, a13,
    a20, a21, a22, a23;

if (a === out) {
    out[12] = a[0] * x + a[4] * y + a[8] * z + a[12];
    out[13] = a[1] * x + a[5] * y + a[9] * z + a[13];
    out[14] = a[2] * x + a[6] * y + a[10] * z + a[14];
    out[15] = a[3] * x + a[7] * y + a[11] * z + a[15];
} else {
    a00 = a[0]; a01 = a[1]; a02 = a[2]; a03 = a[3];
    a10 = a[4]; a11 = a[5]; a12 = a[6]; a13 = a[7];
    a20 = a[8]; a21 = a[9]; a22 = a[10]; a23 = a[11];

    out[0] = a00; out[1] = a01; out[2] = a02; out[3] = a03;
    out[4] = a10; out[5] = a11; out[6] = a12; out[7] = a13;
    out[8] = a20; out[9] = a21; out[10] = a22; out[11] = a23;

    out[12] = a00 * x + a10 * y + a20 * z + a[12];
    out[13] = a01 * x + a11 * y + a21 * z + a[13];
    out[14] = a02 * x + a12 * y + a22 * z + a[14];
    out[15] = a03 * x + a13 * y + a23 * z + a[15];
}

return out;
```

};

with the following call

```js
mat4.translate(mvMatrix,[0, 0, -2.0]);
```

i get the following error: "Cannot read property 0 of undefined" given when it tries to assign the vec3 v components.

Any help with that? Regards

Comment: You're only passing 2 arguments, but the function expects 3.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin i noticed that, but both the in-book code, as well as the github code for the example calls the method as i put it. i tried with three arguments and i don't get an error but still doesn't render.

Comment: i'm wondering if gl-matrix.js changed in the last six months since the last commit and the signature of the method changed??

Comment: Yes, gl-matrix 2.0 came out 2 months ago with a revised incompatible interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of glMatrix used by the book is likely [1.3.7](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/tree/v1.3.7), while the most recently released version is 2.1.0. As of 2.0 the interface has changed for consistency and will not match what you see in the book.

If you want to use the latest and greatest glMatrix, you'll want to refer to the [documentation](http://glmatrix.net/docs/2.1.0/) to get the correct parameters. Otherwise just download 1.3.7 and use it as the book describes.

Comment: its working now!, thanks a lot for your answer and the awesome work with gl-matrix!

Answer (score 3):

Update the new API in gl-matrix:

```
mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 100.0);                                                               
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);                                     
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0, 0, -2.0]);
```

Comment: Though the answer by Toji gives the reason for the error (different versions of glMatrix), this answer by @blessdyb actually gives the solution.  If you are looking at basic WebGL tutorials and want to use the newer versions of glMatrix, updating these three lines in the tutorial code got the tutorials to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**OLD API: gl-matrix-1.x**

```
mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);
```

**New API: gl-matrix-2.x**

```
mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 100.0);                                                               
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I happened to the same problem with the latest glmatrix.min.js. However, after using ver 1.3.7 from  https://www.versioneye.com/javascript/toji:gl-matrix/1.3.7   ,  it was solved.